# How do I join a specific Brawlhalla clan as a limited Steam user?

Tags: steam, brawlhalla

I was playing a random free-for-all match in Brawlhalla and after the match, 2 of the other players were impressed enough with me that they invited me into their clan in the chat. When I asked them to walk me through how to do it, they said to add them to friends on Steam. When I tried doing that, Steam said I wasn't allowed to. I tried to tell the other players that, but I accidentally hit the wrong keys before I opened the chatbox, which made me leave the game lobby and cut me off from those guys. I tried joining a few more matches hoping I'd bump into them again, but no luck.

After looking up details on Steam and elsewhere, I learned that limited Steam accounts have restrictions placed on them if they haven't bought $5.00 USD or at least have that much in their Steam wallet. Now, I don't have ANY money at all to change this, and I won't get some any time soon. So, according to Steam the only way to add friends is if that person adds me instead, assuming they aren't a limited account as well. That's fine and all, but I don't know how to contact those people anymore now that I lost track of them. Is there any way for me to find those specific players and/or their clan and join up, without having to endlessly comb the matchmaking lobbies? I remember their usernames (not their account names) and their Brawlhalla clan name, but I don't know where to go from here. I'm not that familiar with either Steam or Brawlhalla to begin with, and I'm hoping that there's a direct solution I just haven't found.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find them simply go in the community tab in the top and write their names in the search for a person textbox. (you can also find groups that way)

If you want to see who you have played with in the last games:

Go to your profile > Friends > Recently played with

This doesn't always works, it depends on the game !

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

The people you found were just ignorant you can invite people to your clan using the Lobby menu. They just have to use the "Lobby" button in the upper right menu to get your name and they can invite you to their clan by clicking it. Of course, some people may want you as a friend before addind you to their clan though.

If you want to improve in the game and meet nice people, try to join popular clan's discord. You can even play with them before joining.

Answer (score 1):

Ask them to add you instead. 
Unlimited Steam accounts can add Limited steam accounts, So if they were to add you instead you'd be on each other's friend list, Because you accidentally clicked the chatbox away, Do you remember their names? You can look up their names if you do in the Community tab, then comment on their profiles.